# Getting a printing error while assigning vector to data.table column

Tags: r, data.table, knitr

EDITED for brevity:

I have a pair of pre-assigned data.tables with a few tens of thousands of rows each and a handful of columns each. I am trying to aggregate one column from one table and assign the result to the other table.

The problem is that I am getting the following error on assignment:

```
Error in SYS[[length(SYS) - 3L]][[1L]] == "knit_print.default" : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

The code itself doesn't crash, but the error message basically takes the place of the data table when I view/print the return value. Or it appears to do so.

Googling for this finds absolutely nothing except for the Github sourcecode of data.table. So I had a look at it and the only thing similar is around rows 45-50ish, and seems to be about suppressing/delaying print output during in-place assignment. There is no other piece of documentation that I could find about this error.

I also haven't been able to create an MRE yet (still trying), as stripping down the code ends up with working examples, so clearly I'm missing the thing that is breaking it. I suspect that when/if I find it I'll be able to answer my own question.

I'm posting this because I'm hoping someone on here might know what the error means, which would help me in return pinpoint the problem in my code and either fix it or create an MRE around it for a bug report.

Poking around I've determined that assignments in the source code fail (for one table only, no problems with the other), but interrupting the execution and copying the same assignments into the console works fine. So it doesn't seem to be an issue with my syntax or data.

UPDATE: Minimal Reproducible Example

After 3 days I pinpointed the problem.

```
alloc_out <- function(annot = c("a", "b")) {
  Genes <- data.table("parent" = annot, flag = NA)
  ro <- structure(list("Genes" = Genes), class="dtu")
  ro$Genes[, flag := TRUE]  # This causes the error message 
                            # when executed from source, 
                            # but works in console.
  return(ro)
}
```

R version: 3.2.4 in RStudio on OSX El Capitan //
data.table version: 1.9.6

Comment: Adding the knitr tag because, y'know, knit_print.default comes from there.

Comment: Sorry, I think you're going to need a MRE and probably also a shorter description of what goes wrong. The (too-long) code you've added works fine for me, e.g., with `alloc_out(list(parent_id = 1, target_id = 2))`. Once you get an MRE, you might want to post it on a bug/issue tracker for data.table or knitr if it gets no traction here.

Comment: @Frank Managed to narrow it down.

Answer (score 2):

As I suspected, pinpointing the error and creating the MRE went hand-in-hand (and in that order).

The problem in my code is caused by this line:

```
ro <- structure(list("Genes" = Genes), class="dtu")
```

Specifically by the class attribute. For some reason (that is not apparent from the documentation of  strucutre()), the attribute breaks it. If I ommit the attribute assignment, everything works as expected.

This does not really explain why the error happens on a deeper level. Just what causes it in my code.

Comment: Hm, now that I reread this, yeah, I wouldn't expect it to work that way. You might want to file a bug report https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Support

Comment: Thanks @frank. I will.